# Inequality involving bounded mean oscillation(BMO) function

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

I want to prove

$||f|-|f|_B|\leq|f-f_B|+||f||_{BMO}$

where $f_B=\frac 1{m(B)}\int_B f(x)dx$ with $B$ being a ball in $\mathbb{R^d}$, and $f_{BMO}=sup\frac1{m(B)}\int_B |f(x)-f_B|dx<\infty$ where $sup$ is taken over all balls in $\mathbb{R^d}$.
I naively attempted triangle inequality $||f|-|f|_B|\leq |f|+|f|_B\leq |f-f_B|+2|f|$ or $|f-f_B|+2|f|_B$ but this doesn't seem like a good estimate. Can anyone give me any insight on this? Thanks!